# How to use SharePoint FrameWork for SharePoint 2016 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I am having a look at sharepoint framwork tutorials in order to use it in a SharePoint 2016 environment.
However, all tutorials are related to SharePoint OnLine. So, I was wondering whether or not SPFX can be used in Sharepoint 2016.

Is there any sharepoint workbench url in SharePoint 2016 to test SPFX developments ?

Is there any internal CDN where to deploy the SPFX package on in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 8):

To be able to use **SPFX** for **SharePoint Server 2016**, you must first patch you SharePoint Server 2016 with **Feature Pack 2** ([September 2017 Public Update for SharePoint 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates#sharepoint-2016-update-history?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)).

Once it installed, you will be able to upload and deploy SharePoint Framework packages that contain web parts via the SharePoint `App Catalog` just as you would with SharePoint `Add-ins`.

---

**Is there any internal CDN where to deploy the SPFX package on in SharePoint 2016?**

Yes, The CDN path should be the URL of the centralized location on the SharePoint server 2016 or the URL of the SPX Library assets in the SharePoint site.

> **Note:** by default `.json` files are not allowed to be uploaded to SharePoint 2016 libraries. So farm-level settings will need to be adjusted for this option.

For more details check [SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

---

**To get started, you should walk through the below links**

1. [Set up your SharePoint client-side web part development environment.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)
2. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)
3. [Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)
4. [Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

> **For more details check** [SPFx for SharePoint Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

Comment: Maybe MS have updated their webpages recently. The link above are for SP online environment. The support document for on-premise is very limited.